# CloudFormation - Enable TTL for DynamoDB Create Table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I'd like to enable TTL for my newly-created-table via CloudFormation. I've tried the following to no avail:

```
{
  "Resources" : {
    "mytable" : {
      "Type" : "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties" : {
        "TableName" : "my_table",
        "ProvisionedThroughput" : {"ReadCapacityUnits" : 1, "WriteCapacityUnits" : 5},
        "KeySchema" :
        [
          {"AttributeName" : "user_email", "KeyType" : "HASH"},
          {"AttributeName" : "datetime", "KeyType" : "RANGE"}
        ],
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
          {"AttributeName" : "user_email", "AttributeType" : "S"},
          {"AttributeName" : "datetime", "AttributeType" : "S"}
        ],
        "TimeToLiveDescription": {
          "AttributeName": "expire_at", 
          "TimeToLiveStatus": "ENABLED"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I used the TimeToLiveDescription, which I obtained from [this doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-how-to.html#time-to-live-ttl-how-to-enable-cli-sdk).

Attempting to create the stack gave me the following error:

```
Encountered unsupported property TimeToLiveDescription
```

Comment: I did the same thing initially. The attribute TimeToLiveDescription is the output from describing the table, not part of the resource declaration when creating the table. The naming is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The DynamoDB TTL-support for CloudFormation exists now. See:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-dynamodb-timetolivespecification.html

Example:

```
{
  "TableName": "MyTable",
  "AttributeDefinitions": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "Uid",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    }
  ],
  "KeySchema": [
    {
      "AttributeName": "Uid",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    }
  ],
  "ProvisionedThroughput": {
    "ReadCapacityUnits": "1",
    "WriteCapacityUnits": "1"
  },
  "TimeToLiveSpecification": {
    "AttributeName": "TimeToLive",
    "Enabled": "TRUE"
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont understand this example. Means that the Item must have an attribute named "TimeToLive" with attributeType "N"??. Could you provide an example with dynamoDB.putItem() method?

Answer (score 22):

For the sake of completeness, following is an example CloudFromation YAML that creates a Table with TTL enabled

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: The database for my Service

Resources:
  BatchDataTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: "MyDynamoTable"
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: Id
          AttributeType: S
        - AttributeName: SortKey
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema: 
        - AttributeName: Id
          KeyType: "HASH"
        - AttributeName: SortKey
          KeyType: "RANGE"           
      TimeToLiveSpecification:
        AttributeName: TimeToLive
        Enabled: true
```

Now if you add an item to this tabe with an Attribute named "TimeToLive" and have it's value set to the Unix Epoch at which the item should expire, DynamoDB will clear the item from that table when the TTL is reached.

Comment: Shouldn't the attribute names be within double quotes? Or is that just optional?

Comment: It is optional. I try to be consistent with quoting to keep sane :-)

Answer (score 3):

TTL for AWS Dynamo DB is a new feature (launched in Feb 2017) and like Jared mentioned in his answer, it doesn't seem to be supported by AWS Cloudformation just yet. In the meantime, what you could do - if you're launching a new EC2 instance in the same cloudformation template - is to execute (under UserData) the aws cli command you linked to which, would update the TTL `aws dynamodb update-time-to-live --table-name TTLExample --time-to-live-specification "Enabled=true, AttributeName=ttl"`, making a reference to your dynamo db resource (mytable). (Also make sure the instance is using an IAM role with the necessary policies to be able to update this resource).

Comment: Can I execute CLI commands in a template even if I'm not launching a new EC2 instance?

Comment: CLI commands need to be executed on some type of host or environment - so as far as I know the other alternative to this would be by adding a Lambda function that would execute the cli command. You can read a bit more about it here: https://alestic.com/2016/11/aws-lambda-awscli/

I don't know of any other methods.

Comment: The only other method I know, (not within the template) would be by using a build service/server like Jenkis to launch the Cloudformation Stack and then execute the necessary aws command from the build server. (you'd need to install the AWS cli on the server, etc).

Comment: Hi, the ttl is enabled in dynamo but dynamodb only delete the fields of an id but not the record, why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

That link is an example for the AWS CLI.

Support for configuring DynamoDB TTLs has not been added to cloudformation yet.

Comment: It's been added!